# MarkLogic : Custom REST URL construction

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic Version : 9.0-6.2

I have a requirement to build end point URL for a custom REST API as shown below.

https://localhost:8011/v1/resources/customer/registration/preference

so I created folder structure as shown below

```
\plugins\entities\Customer\harmonize\REST\services\customer\registration
```

Inside 'registration' folder, I placed preference.sjs file. When I called the service, I am getting *405:Method not found* error.

But if I place the same exact code (preference.sjs) under

```
\plugins\entities\Customer\harmonize\REST\services\
```

and use the URL https://localhost:8011/v1/resources/preference then I am getting expected results.

Any pointers on how to structure the folder to support the desired URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that directories are supported for [REST API Resource Service Extensions](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_59112).

You could use a delimiter, such as `-` in the `extensionName` instead of directories, in order to organize the extensions and ensure that they are grouped when sorted:

```
\plugins\entities\Customer\harmonize\REST\services\customer-registration-preferences.sjs
```